NestJS: Validate request body against dto when the controller method expects that it can either be an object or an array of objects
Controller code
I have an update method that expects both an object and an array of objects. The issue I'm facing is that when I define in the code that the updateDto is an object, then the validation pipe works fine and strips off the extra keys. However, when I specify that the updateDto can be either an object or an array, the validation doesn't work as expected, and the console indicates that the extra keys are not being stripped off. How can I make it work in this case as well?
I've tried something like this, but it didn't work.
Class validator validate method
